# My ckeditor donot support unicode

Tags: php, ckeditor, editor

I am using **ckeditor**, i want to insert nepali and other language from this editor. But i cannot get the language, it inserts only `?????`. There is no any problem in connection.

I copy the language and paste in **ckeditor** and try to insert in database phpmyadmin. Should i change in config file or add any code or any plugins